# Geometry Nodes: How can a line be turned into dynamic steps?

Tags: geometry-nodes

While most stair/step setups in geometry nodes are parameter driven, I'm trying to create stairs that can be adjusted via one vertex of a two vertex mesh-edge/line that is hooked to an empty:

[image]

an outline can then be made, filled in, and extruded procedurally:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The part that I haven't been able to figure out is the index assignment so that every other point is moved to its proper position dynamically via what I think would be two "set postition" nodes. The first one would take every other point and move it to the *prior* point's x position:

[image]

Then,  the second "set position" node could move the point to the *following* point's z position:

[image]

Theoretically I think this could be easily done by getting the index numbers of the two sets of points to match up for the x position (and then again for the z position), but I haven't been able to figure out the exact node setup for it to work. Any insight or help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, for each second point you need to sample X position from previous point, and Z position from next one. Fixed it in attached file.

[image]

[image]